# Sails + Mongo + Waterline. Sort by count documents in populated collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, sails.js, waterline

I have two models - User and Tag. Part of User model

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {

        tags: {
            collection: "tag",
            via: "users"
        }
}};
```

Tag model looks like

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        name: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        },
        users: {
            collection: "user",
            via: "tags"
        },
}};
```

And I need to sort tags by "users.length" (each tag can has different number of users). I tried this

```
Tag.find().populate('users').sort('users.length DESC').exec(function(err, tags){});
```

And also I tried something like this

```
Tag.native(function (err, collection) {

        if (err) return res.serverError(err);

        collection.aggregate(
            [
                { $sort : { users : -1 } }
            ], function (err, results) {                      
        });

    });
```

But I had a fail. Documents are not sorted in right order. Can you help me to sort documents as I want please? I'm a new in Sails and in Mongo too. And I have no idea how I can do this.

P.S.

I use sails-mongo adapter version 0.11.2

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there's no way of doing this as of now.

I would suggest maintaining a `count` field in the `Tag` model itself and updating it each time a `User` adds or removes a `Tag`. Then run a normal query like you did with `count` as the sort key. Doing this also allows you to query faster if you just need `Tag` information (and not the `users`) since you can skip the `populate()` call which internally references another collection.

Comment: thank you for advice! i did as you say and it working now

Comment: That's great. You can upvote/accept this answer if it solves your problem.